# How to make a working orbit in simulation (python)?

Tags: python, physics, simulator

I have a problem with my simulator regarding not being able to make a body orbit around another, what is the problem here and how do I fix it? I am using atan2 to calculate the angle of the gravitational force, as well as calculating the net force of the gravitational pull and the body's own movement. The gravitational constant (G) is currently not the real constant, for testing purposes.

```
import math
import pygame

pxM = 3000
pygame.init()
width, height = 1920, 1080
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))


class Body:
    def __init__(self, mass, color, x, y, dx, dy, a, vel0, veldir, speed, fdir):
        self.mass = mass
        self.color = color
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.dx = dx
        self.dy = dy
        self.a = a
        self.vel0 = vel0
        self.veldir = veldir
        self.speed = speed
        self.fdir = fdir
        # Creates a Celestial body with the traits, mass (in kg), color (RGB), Position (x, y)
        # vel0 (Initial velocity in Px/s), veldir (direction of Initial velocity in degrees )

    def render(self):
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, self.color, (self.x, self.y), 5,)


M1 = Body(70000000000, (255, 255, 255), 500, 500, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
M2 = Body(1000000, (255, 255, 255), 700, 700, 0, 0, 0, 4, 270, 0, 0)

G = 0.0001
m1 = M1.mass
m2 = M2.mass
r = (M2.x-M1.x)**2+(M2.y-M1.y)**2
F = G * m1 * m2 / r

M1.render()
M2.render()

pygame.display.flip()
while (M1.x, M1.y) != (M2.x, M1.y):
    r = (M2.x - M1.x) ** 2 + (M2.y - M1.y) ** 2
    F = G * m1 * m2 / r
    M1.a = (F/M1.mass) / pxM
    M2.a = (F/M2.mass) / pxM
    M1.speed += M1.a
    M2.speed += M2.a
    M1.fdir = math.atan2(M2.y - M1.y, M2.x - M1.x)
    M2.fdir = math.atan2(M1.y - M2.y, M1.x - M2.x)
    M1.dx = math.cos(M1.fdir) * M1.speed + math.cos(M1.veldir) * M1.vel0
    M1.dy = math.sin(M1.fdir) * M1.speed + math.sin(M1.veldir) * M1.vel0
    M2.dx = math.cos(M2.fdir) * M2.speed + math.cos(M2.veldir) * M2.vel0
    M2.dy = math.sin(M2.fdir) * M2.speed + math.sin(M2.veldir) * M2.vel0
    M1.x += M1.dx
    M1.y += M1.dy
    M2.x += M2.dx
    M2.y += M2.dy
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    M1.render()
    M2.render()
    pygame.display.update()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            break
```

I tried changing how it calculated physics but with no result

Comment: `F = G * m1 * m2 / r` - check your formula, it should be r squared.

Comment: The "speeds" (which I think are your gravitational effect) increase monotonically.  The speed due to gravitation needs to be a vector that changes at each instant.

Comment: Is it not r because of that I used the pythagorean theorem to calculate it so:
a^2 + b^2 = c^2 = r
so r is then distance squared or r^2 or am I wrong?

Comment: Then please don't call it r if you mean the square of r...

Comment: You are missing the usage of `speed` and `vel0`, that is probably wrong. I would also suggest having velocity and acceleration just be vectors instead of dealing with trigonometric functions so much.

Comment: What level of mathematics do you have? It is much easier to compute everything in cartesian x-y coordinates although rather tricky to conserve energy with any of the simple minded integration techniques. ISTR a creative mistake makes one of the simplest ones almost work OK (paper in ~1984 don't recall author). One of the methods that works reasonably well for orbital dynamics is an old Russian method called summed [Numerov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerov%27s_method) ideal for solving x" = f(x) for vector x.

Comment: `M1.speed += M1.a`  is also wrong - speed and acceleration are *vectors*, you can't just add their magnitudes...

Comment: The gravitational force acts (in the opposite direction to) the vector joining the two points. You don’t need to calculate angles. As long as the force is equal and opposite on the two gravitating bodies you will conserve total momentum (irrespective of the accuracy of the subsequent kinematics).